# I want to keep the last two letters if its "ub"

Tags: python, spyder

The goal of the code is to add ub before any vowel (klinker) to a new sentence (nieuwe_zin). or to decode sentences.

I want to add a feature where if the last 2 characters in the zin(sentence) are "ub" they will not be deleted when decoded. So that words like club dont become cl.

```
from pcinput import getString 
    while True: 
    zin = getString("Give a sentence") 
    cd = getString("Coding or decoding (c/d)") 
    cd = cd.lower() 
    klinkers = ("eaiou") 
    nieuwe_zin = ("") zin= zin.lower()
        if cd == "c":
            for i in range (len(zin)):
                if zin[i] in klinkers:
                    nieuwe_zin += "ub" + zin[i] 
                else:
                    nieuwe_zin += zin[i]
            print (nieuwe_zin)
            break
        
        
            
        if cd == "d":
            i = 0
            while i < len(zin):
                if zin[i:i+2] == "ub":
                    i += 2
                if  zin[i:i+4] == "ubub":
                    i += 0
                else:
                    nieuwe_zin += zin[i]
                    i += 1
            print(nieuwe_zin)    
        
            break
        
        else:
            print ("C or D")
```

I tried

`if zin[i:-2] =="ub":`
`i = -1`
`nieuwe_zin = zin + "ub"`

Comment: please fix formatting

Comment: [`endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith)

Comment: python requires correct indentation to work,  please correct this so that users can clearly understand the code.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: To account for multiple instances of "ub" as in "clubub"

```
from pcinput import getString 
while True: 
    zin = getString("Give a sentence") 
    cd = getString("Coding or decoding (c/d)") 
    cd = cd.lower() 
    klinkers = ("eaiou") 
    nieuwe_zin = ("") 
    zin= zin.lower()
    if cd == "c":
        for i in range (len(zin)):
            if zin[i] in klinkers:
                nieuwe_zin += "ub" + zin[i] 
            else:
                nieuwe_zin += zin[i]
        print (nieuwe_zin)
        break
        
    if cd == "d":
            i = 0
            while i < len(zin):
                if zin[i:i+3] == "ubub":
                    i += 3
                nieuwe_zin += zin[i]
                i += 1
            print(nieuwe_zin)    
            break
    else:
        print ("C or D")
```

Cleaned up and optimized version:

```
from pcinput import getString 

while True: 
    zin = getString("Give a sentence").lower() 
    cd = getString("Coding or decoding (c/d)").lower() 
    nieuwe_zin = ""
    klinkers = "eaiou"

    if cd == "c":
        nieuwe_zin = "".join(["ub" + char if char in klinkers else 
        char for char in zin])
        print(nieuwe_zin)
        break

    elif cd == "d":
        i = 0
        while i < len(zin):
            if zin[i:i+3] == "ubub":
                i += 3
            nieuwe_zin += zin[i]
            i += 1
        print(nieuwe_zin)    
        break

    else:
        print("Please enter either 'c' or 'd'.")
```

Comment: Thank you. If i type club it wont break anymore. But if i code club (clubub) it isnt able to decode it back to club

Comment: That is because it only checks for single instances of "ub". You could fix this by using a loop to itereate until none remain.

Comment: Matter of fact it doesnt decode anything if the given sentence ends with ub

Comment: I have edited the first answer with functionality to fix this problem.

Comment: Thank you for helping me but I replaced the if cd == d section with your edited version and it doesn't give me anything back.

Comment: I have edited my comment again, and posted the whole code. It returns "Clubub" when decoding, and "Clubububub" when coding. It should also be mentioned the code can be refactored a bit and cleaned up to optimize. I have posted both versions.